# Implementing Passive Wisdom (Perception)

Tags: dnd-5e

So, once this is calculated (10 plus modifiers), who rolls (assuming a d20???) to see if something is seen/heard/etc...and since modifiers push the number higher for the character, I would assume the roll needs to be under that number for the character to have success? If I am wrong, how does this work?

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question was about all aspects of Passive Perception (including how to calculate it), this is just about how to use it.

Comment: @enkryptor Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a passive skill is that nothing is rolled. You calculate a passive perception as 10+perception.

If there's an enemy stealthing, they roll against the Passive Perception. If they roll the same or higher than PCs passive perception then they're unseen. If they roll below, they're detected.

Comment: A note to improve this answer, add how this keeps the game flowing, and can prevent the players from being alerted to something that the characters aren't alerted to.  (A call to roll perception is always a good hint there is something to see, even if the characters don't see it)

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused then. If there is nothing rolled for Passive Wisdom (percecption) then why allocate a number to it? Its just random? Is the number just for me to roll, having enemies (monsters) succeed if I roll over the character's Passive Wisdom?

Comment: I should also mention this was specifically in regards to Passive Wisdom (perception) which is calculated by taking 10 and adding Wisdom modifier, not perception. This is per page 175 in the PHB.

Comment: @JimBeasley yes (to the last one). A classic example is Stealth. The monster makes a stealth check (lets say they get a 14). You then compare that number to the PC's passive perception scores. Anyone with a Passive Perception higher than 14 notices the monster, everyone else doesn't.

Comment: @JimBeasley Passive Perception Score can be seen as a form of AC specifically for perception.  (sorta).